# Big difference in stored procedure execution time from Node and in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, node.js, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

My procedure ran from Node.js (Azure Mobile Services) tooks 5.7 seconds (time between start of `success` callback and sending a query).
The same procedure ran with the same parameters from SSMS took 0.4 second.

How can I debug this problem?

My ideas of problem source are:

- bad execution plans
- bad connection settings for Node.js (probably it can't be changed)
- slow connection between Node.js and Azure SQL Server
- problems with driver (Azure uses [this beta version of node-sqlserver](https://github.com/paulbatum/node-sqlserver) internally)

Comment: The source of problem is `node-sqlserver` that fails to deal with big data (2500 rows, 30 columns) resulting in insane cost of parsing and allocating objects. In-depth answer should be published in few days.

Answer (score 1):

Check the online Azure SQL Database Management Tool's Query Performance section to see the execution plan of the actual queries being executed by Node.js, and you should be able to track it down. This is in the Silverlight-based management tool accessed from the Manage button in the Azure portal database page.

One potential culprit is that all string values coming from Node are NVARCHARs. If your procedure is comparing a parameter to an indexed CHAR, VARCHAR or UNIQUEIDENTIFIER column, the database will have to do an implicit cast and index scan. Any indexed column needs to be an NVARCHAR (or maybe NCHAR) to get optimal performance querying it from Node.